# What does the term "bitcode" mean?

Tags: xcode, warnings, terminology, bitcode

Having updated to Apple's latest and greatest, Xcode 7.0 beta, I noticed the term "bitcode" used in a few warnings.

What does the term "bitcode" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AppThinning/AppThinning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH35-SW2):

> *Bitcode* is an intermediate representation of a compiled program. Apps
>   you upload to iTunes Connect that contain bitcode will be compiled and
>   linked on the App Store. Including bitcode will allow Apple to
>   re-optimize your app binary in the future without the need to submit a
>   new version of your app to the store.

It seems to be the product of some sort of partial compilation, allowing Apple to perform minor optimizations without the need for you to resubmit your application.